# Image upload issue on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Please help me on below issue:

This is my code:
ASPX code:

```
<input type="Button" id="BtnUpload" class="button1" value="Upload Image" onclick="clickFileUpload();" />
```

Javascript function on ASPX page:

```
function UploadImage(path) //Added by Archana on 14-Aug-2013
{         

 var Sketch_Code,url,str;
 Sketch_Code= document.getElementById('<%=txtCode.ClientID%>').value;
 var strPage,strWidthProperty ;
 var retVal=""; 
 if(Sketch_Code !="")
 {
   if(path!="" && path!=null)
  {
//  var timeout = setTimeout("Imageresize(path,Sketch_Code);", 5000);
//  alert(timeout);
  var img = Imageresize(path,Sketch_Code);
  if (document.getElementById('<%=imgload.ClientID%>').complete) 
  {alert("loaded");
  url = "<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SiteURL").ToString() %>Upload_Images/800x800/" ;
   document.getElementById('<%=imgload.ClientID%>').src =url + img;
   document.getElementById('<%=imagePath.ClientID%>').value=img;
  }

  }
}
}

function clickFileUpload() 
 {
      $('input[type=file]:first').trigger('click');
      var imgpath=document.getElementById("imgfile").value;
         //alert(imgpath);
           if(imgpath =='') 
          {
            // There is no file selected 
            alert("Please select valid file.");
          }
          else
          {
            var Extension = imgpath.substring(imgpath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toUpperCase();
            if (Extension == "BMP" || Extension == "JPG" || Extension == "JPEG" || Extension == "GIF" || Extension == "PNG" )
            {
                UploadImage(imgpath);// Valid file type          
            }
            else
            {
             // Not valid file type
                  alert("Please select valid extension file. (.bmp,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif)");
            }
           }
}

 function Imageresize(e,c)
{
    //alert(e.id);
    var Imagename = e; 
    var Code=c;
    $.ajax({async : false, 
                  type : 'GET', /*callback: function(index){CalculateTotal()},*/
                  url : "ImageResizer.aspx?Sketch_Code="+ c +"&imagepath=" + e, 
                  success : function(response)
                    {
                        setTimeout('checkForAllImagesLoaded()', 5);
                        ImagesString = response;
                        // var ArrValues = ImagesString.split("~");


                    }

            });
     return ImagesString;        
}
```

This is my code on ImageResizer page:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Partial Class ImageResizer
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public Shared Function ResizeImage(ByVal image As Image, ByVal path As String, ByVal size As Size, Optional ByVal preserveAspectRatio As Boolean = True) As Image
        Dim newWidth As Integer
        Dim newHeight As Integer
        If preserveAspectRatio Then
            Dim originalWidth As Integer = image.Width
            Dim originalHeight As Integer = image.Height
            Dim percentWidth As Single = CSng(size.Width) / CSng(originalWidth)
            Dim percentHeight As Single = CSng(size.Height) / CSng(originalHeight)
            Dim percent As Single
            percent = IIf(percentHeight < percentWidth, percentHeight, percentWidth)
            newWidth = CInt(originalWidth * percent)
            newHeight = CInt(originalHeight * percent)
        Else
            newWidth = size.Width
            newHeight = size.Height
        End If
        Dim newImage As Image = New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
        Using graphicsHandle As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
        End Using
        newImage.Save(path)
        Return newImage
    End Function

    Function UploadFileToServer(ByVal filepath As String, ByVal code As String) As String
        Dim scriptStr As String = ""
        Dim FileName As String
        Try
            Dim fileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(filepath).ToLower()
            FileName = code.Trim() + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "") + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + fileExtension
            File.Copy(filepath, Server.MapPath("Upload_Images/") & FileName)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return FileName
    End Function

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim filepath, resizedpath, code As String
        filepath = Request.QueryString("imagepath")
        code = Request.QueryString("Sketch_Code")
        If filepath <> "" Then
            filepath = UploadFileToServer(filepath, code)
            Dim original As Image = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("Upload_Images/") & filepath)
            resizedpath = Server.MapPath("Upload_Images/200X200/") & filepath
            ResizeImage(original, resizedpath, New Size(200, 200))
            resizedpath = Server.MapPath("Upload_Images/800X800/") & filepath
            ResizeImage(original, resizedpath, New Size(800, 800))
            Response.Expires = -1
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
            Response.Write(filepath.ToString())
            Response.End()
        End If


    End Sub
End Class
```

This code is working fine on my local(development environment)
But my code is not working for $.ajax function when I try to upload after deploying this on server. Unable to get the response which returning my imagestring.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

it returns you,GDI Error. ?

For GDI Error Refer this:

It's Because of "Upload_Images/" directory is missing.

so to get proper Location of

**You have to write following Code in Catch block to print**

```
 Response.Write(Server.MapPath("Upload_Images/"));
```

this will return correct path of Upload_Images folder.